# Adding a DIV inside another DIV shows scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #00FF00">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 300px; top: 45px; height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #FF0000;"></div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Why does the `div` gets pushed outside of the viewing area and hence showing the scrollbars. If you check toward the top right corner, the black area is the extension when the red `div` moved.

How can I edit it so the red `div` has the top and the left position but doesn't extend beyond the page width and height?

Comment: Check this out, it happens to you because overflow is set to visible by default: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Hiding the overflow will not solve the real problem here. You are giving it a position relative to the parent container, but it still has a height/width of 100%, so it will extend beyond the bounds of the parent container. Instead of relative positioning you could use padding or margins to achieve the position you want, without creating overflow.

Comment: I am using PIXEL for left and top for the second DIV instead of percentage. How can I work with that?

Comment: Don't use relative positioning, it is already a child element of the parent div, and won't leave the bounds of the parent. Use top and left margins instead to position it.

Comment: Without positioning the right and top doesn't have any effect

Comment: substitute top/left for margin-top/margin-left (or simply `margin:x 0 0 x`). It does essentially the same thing: creates a *clear* spacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To actually answer the "why" of the question:

The reason you're getting scroll bars is that the relative positioned div inside of the absolute is set to 100% width and height, but ALSO is displaced (in this case, by top and left)

It is therefor assuming 100% width/height of the parent container AND displacing it, causing it to be too large.

By adding `overflow:hidden`, you seemingly solve this issue, but any content past that will be clipped, not actually fitting inside the dimensions you have set.

Another way to do this would be something like...

```
top: 10%;
left: 10%;
width:90%;
height:90%;
```

You could just as easily substitute top and left for padding/margin of that direction.

Comment: How do I avoid using the `overflow: hidden` so the text and/or any contents expanding beyond the page width and height will show a scrollbar, otherwise it wont?

Comment: see updated answer. it's all about making it fit. unfortunately, you can't use pixels **and** percentages without using javascript, as there's no way to tell what 100% will *actually* translate to using CSS.

Comment: DAMN IT!!!.... I guess it will be a guesstimate since I am using pixel for positioning everywhere else :/

Comment: My recommendation would be to stop using pixels now and fix the *everywhere else* before it grows out of control. **What happens when your page gets viewed on a screen with a different size than yours?** 99% of the web may be using a different size than what you're developing on. Try using control+(+|-) to resize it or view it using http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ to see what's *really* going on.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not LIVE yet so can't test it out with quirktools but I will keep it handy for future.

Comment: When it was pixel when I zoomed in the object stayed in place, but with percentage, it doesn't. The object looses it's position.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48610/discussion-between-kcdwayne-and-sikni8)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3's calc() function to set the second div's height and width to be the same as the first one's, minus the left and top offsets. This will also allow you to use `position: absolute` in your text, aligning it to the right:

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #00FF00">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 300px; top: 45px; height: calc(100% - 45px); width: calc(100% - 300px); background-color: #FF0000;">
        <span style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50%;">TESTING THIS OUT</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Filly/jn2cf/). I also added a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) to get rid of the body margins that the browser might add. If you want to use this reset in your HTML file, create a `<style>` tag inside your `<head>` tag, with the code that is showing in the CSS section in the JSFiddle. If you don't want to use the entire reset, the only actually relevant part is `body { margin: 0px; }`, so you can also add `style="margin: 0px;"` to your `body` tag.

Comment: Wow... Works!!! Adding this: `<span style="position: relative; right: 0; top: 50%;">TESTING THIS OUT</span>` inside the second div, I am expecting the text to be aligned right, but it's aligned left. The top is working correctly.

Comment: This will only hide the problem - your red `div` is still overflowing...as you add content that reaches the bottom, you'll start having problems again.

Comment: That's what I am looking to avoid. How can I set it so the red only goes to the edge of right and bottom?

Comment: Change that span for `<span style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50%;">`. The absolute position of an element is limited by its parent's relative position.

Comment: Can't see the text anymore. Not sure where it is even